# Show own layer or points on Google Maps Navigation for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application for Android I want to show points from my back-end application. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there are no intents or integration APIs for the Navigation application.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will need to have an activity which extends MapActivity and you need a Maps API key, so that it can show the Google map. Then you can add the points from your back-end app to an ItemizedOverlay and they should display ok.